# Mult-line Svg tooltip

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

I have created numerous polygon shapes in SVG format. and grouped them together.
When the user hovers over the group a tooltip box appear. I have used ecmascript. 
What i am looking to do is make the tooltip box a multiline box.
Any ideas how to do this?

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

    function init(evt)
    {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null )
        {
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
        }

        tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
        tooltip_bg = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_bg');

    }

    function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext)
    {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",evt.clientX+17);
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",evt.clientY+14);
        tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");

        length = tooltip.getComputedTextLength();
        tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",length+8);
        tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",evt.clientX+14);
        tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",evt.clientY+1);
        tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visibile");
    }


    function HideTooltip(evt)
    {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }

    ]]>
  </script>
<SVG>
<g onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'GHANA 2000')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
    <path fill="#EEEEEE" d="M250,0c47,0,85.183,10.506,125,33.494L250,250V0z"/>
    <path id="score" d="M250,57c36.284,0,65.761,8.11,96.5,25.857L250,250V57z"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M250,0c47,0,85.183,10.506,125,33.494L250,250V0z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 283.9883 92.0024)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'WalkwayBlack'" font-size="16">62</text>
</g>

<rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" width="55" height="17" visibility="hidden"/>
<text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text>
<SVG>
```

Comment: do you mean to wrap the SVG text inside the box?

Answer (score 0):

You could create more `<text>` elements or `<tspan>` elements within the existing text element, put subsequent lines of text in the additional elements and then position each text/tspan below the previous ones by giving them the same x attribute value and increase the y attribute by the height of the bounding box of the previous line.

Alternatively and more simply, just create `<title>` elements as children of the polygon shape elements and put the multiline text directly within that and the tooltips will be shown by most UAs as multiline tooltips, it certainly works in Firefox and Opera. Here's a [html example](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/test/moz/title-attribute.html) but it should work just as well with SVG except that SVG has a title element rather than a title attribute.

Comment: So i have done the tspan option and the tooltip no longer follows the mouse?

Comment: I don't see why that would happen assuming you're still setting the x, y attributes based on evt.clientX and evt.clientY with some offsets.